# ways to read a text file in golfscript and print out its content

Tags: golfscript

```
'#{File.read("file")}' puts
```

Does not work. Is it possible to read in the content of a text file in `GolfScript`?

Comment: You know, there's a dedicated [code golf site](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) from StackExchange.

Comment: @SayemAhmed yes, but that site is for code challenges, not questions like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#{...}` expansion only occurs with double-quoted strings:

```
"#{File.read('file')}" puts
```

works fine.

However, there are [some catches](http://www.cheddarmonk.org/golfscriptblog/2011/10/debugging-revisited.html).

1. If you want `'file'` to be a parameter, you have to delay the expansion.
2. The result is cached the first time, so if you want to read the same file more than once (e.g. to check for changes) you have to ensure that the expanded value changes. The easiest way I know to do this is to expand `"#{File.read('file')#1}"`, `"#{File.read('file')#2}"`, etc.