# read in a file containing numbers and do squaring before print out on one line

Tags: golfscript

I am learning `golfscript`, and I want to read in a file containing numbers and do squaring before print out on one line. For example, I have a file like the following

```
1
2
3
4
```

Then I need to print out

`1 4 9 16`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code gives you an idea, how to accomplish the task.

```
;                             # Discard the input (golfscript takes 
                              # input from STDIN)

"#{File.read('input.txt')}"   # Read contents of file into a string
                              # (see your previous question 
                              # http://stackoverflow.com/q/17826704)

[~]                           # Evaluate the input into an array

{2?}%                         # Apply the operators `2?` to each element
                              # ( "x 2 ?" simply calculates x^2 )

" "*                          # Join the array elements with spaces

                              # By default the remaining items on the stack
                              # are printed when the program ends
```

You find details to each of the operators [here](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/builtin.html).